# the login.php can be bypassed by deleting it from the address bar

Tags: php

The website is password protected, however visitors can bypass the login screen by deleting it from http://www.sitename/directory/login.php and go directly to the index page.  I can't seem to find the correct code to put into the index page to redirect non-authenticated users back to login.php

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}
$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
$_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
$loginUsername=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
$MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "index.php";
$MM_redirectLoginFailed = "login.php";
$MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
mysql_select_db($database_name, $name);

$LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT memberUser, MemberPass FROM administrators WHERE memberUser=%s AND MemberPass=%s",
GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

$LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $name) or die(mysql_error());
$loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
if ($loginFoundUser) {
 $loginStrGroup = "";

$_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
$_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
}
header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
}
else {
header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried something out?

Comment: _“The website is password protected”_ – well obviously it _isn’t_ …

Comment: In the future, questions that contain code, and things you have tried already are more helpful. Besides, this is a duplicate of like a million questions on SO. A simple google search will yield the same result.

Comment: @JustinE  Thank you Justin for your reply.  I'm learning php as I go and the website I'm updating was created by a different programmer.  I inserted the code you sent me for the Index.php which corrected the bypass issue, however I'm just sorting through the login.php code.  I'm not entirely sure where the issue is, but there's too much code to fit in this comment field.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ will allow you to paste large amounts of code. If you want to paste the urls you receive from pastebin here, I can take a look and possible help a bit more.

Comment: @JustinE I edited the question to include the code from the login.php page I'm working on.

Comment: Also, instead of checking the "$_SESSION" for being set, you should specify an offset, like... if (!isset($_SESSION['MM_Username']))

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: @JustinE I don't understand php very well, I'm sure I'll be able to figure it out from here though. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you declare a session variable, and check for the presence of that variable on the index page. If it doesn't exist, do a redirect to the login page.

Login.php

```
<?php
Session_start();
//Successful login
$_SESSION['logged_in']=TRUE;
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
    Header('Location: login.php');
}
?>
```

Doing this will make sure no one can access the index page without first being directed to the login page.